# Invoke specific Action when Bixby capsule launched

Tags: bixby

What would be the equivalent of a LaunchRequest handler in a Bixby capsule. It would be helpful to the user to have a "Welcome" action along with matching a corresponding view which can give a welcome message along with some initial [conversation drivers](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/collection.conversation-drivers).

```
action (Welcome) {
  type (Search)
  description (Provides welcome message to user.)
  output (?)
}
```

What do you need to add to the action so it is matched right after the capsule is invoked? What would the type() of a "Welcome" capsule be?

What should the output be? The action isn't really outputting a concept but rather just prompting the user to involve one of the other actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bixby is not designed to have a generic "Welcome" page when a capsule is launched.

When a user invokes Bixby, they do so with a goal already in mind. If your capsule has been enabled by the user and its purpose matches the user's request, your capsule will be used to fulfill the user's request.

Since your capsule will be only be invoked by a user request for information/procedure (there is no "Hi Bixby, open XYZ capsule"), you would only need to address the use cases you would like to handle.

If you want to provide information regarding your capsule and the types of utterances a user can try, you should define a capsule-info.bxb file and a hints file.

The contents of these files will be shown in the Marketplace where all released capsules are presented to Bixby users to enable at their discretion.

I would recommend reading through the [deployment checklist](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/deploying.checklist) to give you a better idea of all the supporting information and metadata that you can define to help users find and understand the functionality of your capsule.

Comment: "When a user invokes Bixby, they do so with a goal already in mind. If your capsule has been enabled by the user and its purpose matches the user's request, your capsule will be used to fulfill the user's request."  What if there are multiple capsules enabled that can handle the request, or if there is a "native" experience?

Comment: sarkon - most capsules currently use named dispatch e.g. "Hi Bixby, ask My Capsule to start" etc where "My Capsule" is the dispatch-name defined in capsule-info.bxb - this is similar to other voice assistants. In the future, more capabilities beyond named dispatch will be available including being the default when making a request. If two capsules can both be defaults, the user will be asked which capsule they want to fulfill the request - they can also choose a default. Try enabling Uber and Lyft for ride sharing to see this in action.

Answer (score 2):

Most capsules desiring this feature are using "start", "begin" or "open" and the like (your capsule may have something else logical that makes sense). In your training, simply add those with the goal being the action you want to start your capsule.

Comment: When I am outside the capsule ,If this is text suppose - "Hi Bixby, ask MyCapsule to start" and I just need to add "start" in my training with the goal,right?

Comment: Yes that would work as expected e.g. your example you would train "start" for the goal. If you want to see this in action, try the Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock capsule in the marketpalce e.g. you can say "Hi Bixby, ask Lizard Spock to start"

Answer (score 2):

**How Named Dispatch Works**

The current en-US dispatch patterns are the following:

- "with %dispatch-name% ..."
- "in %dispatch-name% ..."
- "ask %dispatch-name% ..."
- "ask %dispatch-name% for ..."
- "ask %dispatch-name% to ..."

The current ko-KR dispatch pattern is the following:

- %dispatch-name% 에서 ...

When Bixby is processing an utterance, it uses the above dispatch pattern to identify which capsule to use, then passes the rest of the user's phrase to the capsule for interpretation.

For example, consider if the example.bank had the following code block in its capsule-info.bxb file:

```
dispatch-name (ACME bank)
```

If you ask Bixby "Ask ACME bank to open", the "Ask ACME bank" phrase is used to point to the example.bank capsule. The example.bank capsule interprets accordingly its trained in your model with the goal with the word '**open**' ,suppose here a welcome greetings.

Check the [documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/capsule-info.dispatch-name) with "How Named Dispatch Works" which is similar to above description.